# Using jQuery .append() to insert a div into a table cell

Tags: jquery

I'm attempting to create divs in an table using jQuery.  The table represents a calendar with each `<td>` having an ID that is equal to the ISO formatted date string.  In the code below I'm having a problem with the append line.  It is not adding anything to the DOM.  I've checked the tdID values against the IDs for the cells and they do indeed match.  So I'm fairly certain that is not the issue.  Can someone spot where I may have gone wrong?

```
if (loopDate.between(past, future)) {
   var tdID = loopDate.toISOString();
   $("#" + tdID).append("<div class=&quot Event &quot>" 
                   + data.events[i].Est + "</div>");
}
```

Edit --- here's a sample of my html.  The "d" is a character I added to the beginning of the ID to address the issue noted by @Matt Stauffer.

```
<td id="d2012-02-01T05:00:00.000Z">1</td>
```

Comment: Does the #tdID exist in your html? (Whatever the generated tdID is)

Comment: Yes it does.  And I compared the id in the HTML to the tdID variable in my loop.  They match.

Comment: Now that you've shown with the edit what that generated tdID is, check my answer below and i hope it fixes your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that i see your id, although it is valid as a naming convention for the id attribute as for [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#type-id) where:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

the problem in your case is in the use of dots (.) and colons(.) as when you are using the jquery selector, the dot(.) is interpreted as [searching for a class or subclass](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) and the colon(:) [as searching for :first, :last etc](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)

To solve your problem you could try replacing those characters with undescores(_) or hyphens(-) which should be fine.

You can check this [over here at this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FkghZ/1/)

Comment: Thank you. That is indeed the solution.  +1 because you earned it!

Answer (score 3):

Don't use `&quot`; you need a lexical `"` there.
You need to Javascript-escape the string literal by writing `\"`.

Comment: Thanks.  I'll fix that.  However I don't think that's the only issue.  I have the same problem inserting"<div>hello world</div>.

Answer (score 2):

ID's can't start with a number, and I believe an ISO-formatted date would start with a number, so you're using invalid IDs.

Also, as others have mentioned,

```
"<div class=&quot Event &quot>"
```

Should be

```
"<div class=\"Event\">"
```

Comment: Yes, they do start with a number.  I just applied a quick fix by adding a "d" to the beginning of each id.  However, problem still not solved.  +1 for getting me part way there.

Answer (score 1):

You're using escaped HTML entities in the append function, so you need to change:

```
"<div class=&quot Event &quot>"
```

to:

```
"<div class='event'>"...
// or
"<div class=\"event\">"...
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
$(div).addClass("Event");
$(div).append(data.events[i].Est);
$("#" + tdID).append(div);
```

-- much cleaner type of coding...

Answer (score 0):

```
if (loopDate.between(past, future)) {
  var tdID = loopDate.toISOString();
  var tdDiv = document.createElement('div');
  tdDiv.addClass("Event");
  tdDiv.html(data.events[i].Est);
  $("#" + tdID).html(tdDiv);
}
```